# Rails collection_check_boxes include ActiveStorage image in generated checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Assuming the following class

```
class Option
  has_one_attached :photo
end

= collection_check_boxes(:post, :option_ids, Option.all, :id, :name) do |option|
  .checkbox
    = option.check_box(class: "check")
    = option.photo
    = option.label
```

I'd love to be able to include an image next to each checkbox, but I can't find a documented way to do it.  Is there a way I can include an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= collection_check_boxes(:post, :option_ids, Option.all, :id, :name) do |option|
  .checkbox
    = option.check_box(class: "check")
    = image_tag(option.object.photo)
    = option.label
```

> There are also three special methods available: object, text and value, which are the current item being rendered, its text and value methods, respectively.
> - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes